# Запуск ReactPhp Server для нескольких пользователей

Tags: php, reactphp

Есть запушеный ReactPHP Server в консоли, который в стороннем api сервисе по Логину и пароля пользователя делает авторизацию и ставит слушание на нужный метод. После чего данные загружаются в базу.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы несколько пользователей могли использовать 1 запушенный ReactPHP Server. 
Как добиться такого результата?

Вот код самого ReactPHP Server

```
class RealtimeController extends \yii\console\Controller {

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $username = 'test';
        $password = 'test';
           /////// CONFIG ///////
        $debug = true;
        $truncatedDebug = false;

        $ig = new ApiService();
        try {
            $loginResponse = $ig->login($username, $password);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            print $ex->getMessage();
            die;
        }
        // Create main event loop.
        $loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        if ($debug) {
            $logger = new \Monolog\Logger('rtc');
            $logger->pushHandler(new \Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler('php://stdout', \Monolog\Logger::INFO));
        } else {
            $logger = null;
        }
        // Create HTTP server along with Realtime client.
        $httpServer = new RealtimeHttpServer($loop, $ig, $logger);
        // Run main loop.
        $loop->run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение. Не знаю на сколько это правильно, но главное результат.
Так как я использую Yii2 console сделал такой вариант

```
class RealtimeController extends \yii\console\Controller {
    public $login;
    public $pass;
    public function options($actionID)
    {
        return ['login', 'pass'];
    }
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $username = $this->login;
        $password = $this->pass;
        $debug = true;
        $truncatedDebug = false;
        $ig = new ApiService();
        try {
            $loginResponse = $ig->login($username, $password);
        }
        catch (Exception $ex) {
            print $ex->getMessage();
            die;
        }
        $loop = \React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
        $httpServer = new RealtimeHttpServer($loop, $ig, $logger);
        $loop->run();
    }
}
```

Далее написал такой скрипт который бы запустил скрипт в консоле

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isPost()) {
    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();
    exec("nohup yii realtime --login=$post['login'] --pass=$post['pass']");
}
```

Вот и сказочке конец))